# Music player with "time tags/marks"

Tags: music, mp3

The devices I need are a Windows 10 PC, and a android 4.2 Samsung S3 mini.

I have big mp3 that are entire albums. Problems include: I want to listen to particular song, I have to guess the starting time, I can't have all the initial times of all the songs in my memory, so i have to guess. I don't even have the song list with me when I'm with my phone, so I have to "scroll trough" the entire album to find the song.

I could split the albums into songs, that solves that problem. But there are many others as I will point out, and a small feature would solve them all.

Problem 2: When in INSIDE a song , i want to reach a part I like. I don't remember or know exactly when it happens, so it's annoying.
Problem 3: The "time control bar" (it's a horizontal bar wich let's you pick wich time you want to go in the song) is imprecise, and the longer the song the more imprecise, doesn't let me repeat comfortably at all parts I like.

I would like a music player wich has a feature for bookmarking times of songs so I can access quicly the part that I want, be an album or a individual song.
I imagine this is hard, because for every album you have to create a associated file with tags. But if it exist, it will be VERY useful for me, a hardcore music listener and player.

Comment: Does a solution have to work for Android *and* Windows (i.e., you want to synchronize the files with the bookmarks)? Or could a solution be either for Android or for Windows?

Comment: @unor That synchronization would be AWESOME, but I will be very happy with a more humble result!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Replayer](https://replayer.app/en), which offers cues into music files. It's however more suited to a band/choir rehearsal scenario, not for large personal music library.

[image: Replayer on on a phone]

- Allows to define and seek to an arbitrary set of cues per track
- It's browser-based, so working on all major platforms
- can handle MP3 among other formats
- Offers an export function that allows to save and share the cues along with the songs.

Disclaimer: I am the author.